# UNIX Domain Sockets - long String problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, unix-socket

I tried to send a quite long string (abt 40000 characters) via a UNIX Domain Socket in node.js. But it does not send it right. at the receiver I get some parts of the string multiple times...
Any Idea whats the problem here?

The receiver is a node.js app
I send it via

> nc -U /tmp/node.sock

heres the node.js code I use to receive the message

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
}).listen('/tmp/node.sock');
```

Comment: I edited my question and added some code

Comment: Under UNIX, 'length' is always a problem. If you don't mind, just try break it down into app-level packages.

Comment: but why does he receive a small part of the message multiple times? Why is the string not just cut of?

Comment: `data` events can be emitted any number of times with any number of bytes in each event. If you mean you're getting duplicate bytes when you're not sending duplicate bytes, that's a separate issue.

Comment: I just created a unix Socket with socat...same issue. Any Ideas?